# Does each SignalR hub has a dedicated websocket

Tags: websocket, signalr

Assuming both browser & Server supports a web-socket connection.

If I've got 2 hubs on my SignalR server. and my SignalR client connects to both. does that mean that my signalR client will open up 2 separate web-socket connections to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SignalR v2+, hubs will share the same connection. I've had systems with connections to 4+ hubs without performance issue.

Question is a bit of a duplicate of: [Multiple signalR connections/hubs on your website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764360/multiple-signalr-connections-hubs-on-your-website#22151160)

Comment: Thanks for the link mate!